# Polymer: Evaluate expression after ajax response

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have custom polymer component that will load my translations for whole application. Here is the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-expressions/polymer-expressions.html">
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<polymer-element name="nz-i18n" hidden>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      Polymer('nz-i18n', {

          /**
           * our messages container
           */
          messages: {},

          /**
           * what loading is in progress
           */
          loading: {},

          created: function() {
              var self = this;
              // create new expression, to be used for translate method
              PolymerExpressions.prototype.$$ = function(key, params) {
                  // IMPORTANT !!! the scope here is the element we call this function from
                  // set this element as parent of the translator
                  self.parent = this;
                  // get translation
                  return self.translateMessage(key, params);
              };

              // restore loaded messages from local storage
              //this.restoreFromLocalStorage();
          },

          /**
           * Load messages from local storage
           */
          restoreFromLocalStorage: function() {
              // check if we have translations already loaded
              try {
                  if (translations = localStorage.getItem('nz-messages')) {
                      // convert JSON string representation to object
                      this.messages = JSON.parse(translations);
                      return true;
                  }
              } catch (e) {
                  // nothing to do
                  // we will load translations on demand
              }
          },

          /**
           * Translate message by given key and additional parameters
           *
           * IMPORTANT !!!do not use translate as the method name
           * there is such a property in the element
           *
           * @param key - key to be translated
           * @param params - additional parameters
           */
          translateMessage: function(key, params) {
              // set default parameters if not defined
              if (!params || params == 'undefined') {
                  var params = {};
              }
              if (!params.module) {
                  params.module = 'System';
              }

              var msg;
              if (this.messages[params.module]) {
                  // module messages are already loaded
                  try {
                      // try to get translation
                      msg = this.messages[params.module].messages[key] || key;
                      // key with multiple forms has been provided
                      if (typeof(msg) == "object") {
                          if (params.n != '' && params.n != 'undefined') {
                              //get index if the translation in function of the rules 
                               eval('idx = ' + this.messages[params.module].pluralRules.replace('n', params.n) + ';');
                              msg = msg[idx] || key;
                          } else {
                              msg = msg[0];
                          }
                      }
                  } catch (e) {
                      //no translation - return the key
                      msg = key;
                  }
              } else {
                  // module messages are not loaded
                  // start loading
                  this.loadTranslations(params.module);
                  // this will be processed very customly
                  msg = '';
              }

              return msg;
          },

          /**
           * Load messages for the module requested
           *
           * @param module - messages module
           * @param force - if we have to force loading even if
           *                messages for the module are already loaded
           */
          loadTranslations: function(module, force) {
              // set defaults
              if (!module) {
                  module = 'System';
              }
              // check if translations for this module are loaded
              // or if loading is in progress
              if (!this.loading[module] && (force || !this.messages[module])) {
                  // noooooooo - we will load them
                  this.loading[module] = true;
                  // create ajax request
                  ajax = document.createElement('core-ajax');
                  ajax.auto = true;
                  ajax.method = 'GET';
                  ajax.handleAs = 'json';
                  ajax.headers = {
                      "Accept": "application/json",
                      "Content-type": "application/json"
                  };
                  ajax.url = window.basePath + 'api/translations';
                  ajax.params = {"module": module};
                  // register event listeners for the response and post response processing
                  ajax.addEventListener('core-response', this.handleResponse);
                  ajax.parent = this;
                  // do not uncomment this - http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
                  //ajax.xhrArgs = {sync: true};
              }
          },

          /**
           * Process messages loading request
           */
          handleResponse: function() {
              // IMPORTANT !!!! core-ajax scope is here
              if (this.response) {
                  for (module in this.response) {
                      // add current response to the translations
                      this.parent.messages[module] = this.response[module];
                      // remove loading flag for this module messages
                      delete this.parent.loading[module];
                  }
                  // set translations in local storage
                  localStorage.setItem('nz-messages', JSON.stringify(this.parent.messages));
              }
          }
      });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I have also another element that will be used as a frameset and will host all my other application elements:

```
<link href="../../polymer/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html" rel="import">
<link href="../../polymer/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="nz-frameset">
  <template>
    <link href="nz-frameset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <core-header-panel flex>
      <!-- HEADER -->
      <core-toolbar justify="between">
        <img id="logo" src="../../images/logo.png" />
        <div id="title">{{ $$('header_title') }}</div>
      </core-toolbar>
      <!-- CONTENT -->
      <div class="content">{{ $$('num', {n: 4}) }}</div>
    </core-header-panel>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <core-toolbar bottomJustify="around">
      <footer class="bottom">
        {{ $('footer') }}
      </footer>
    </core-toolbar>
  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      Polymer('nz-frameset', {
          ready: function() {

          },
      });
  </script
</polymer-element>
```

And here is my body(all imports needed are in the HEAD):

```
<body fullbleed vertical layout unresolved>
  <!-- INITIALIZE TRANSLATOR -->
  <nz-i18n></nz-i18n>
  <!-- LOAD FRAMESET -->
  <nz-frameset flex vertical layout></nz-frameset>
</body>
```

The problem is that when I open my APP for the first time and no translations are loaded yet, after I update my messages container the expressions does not re-bind and i can not see any text. On refresh(messages are in the local storage already), everything works like a charm.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I saw right from the get-go is that the expressions will only be evaluated once since there is no observable value in it, e.g. the observer doesn't see a variable reference and can detect changes.

This might be a hack, but I would pass a "changeable variable" and filter it in the expression, e.g.

```
<div id="title">{{ n_translate | $$('header_title') }}</div>
```

Now you need to fire an event whenever you load a new translation, in your handle `handleResponse` just add:

```
this.fire("translationChanged");
```

In every module that uses translations, you need to add a event observer:

```
this.addEventListener("translationChanged", function() {
 this.n_translate = new Date(); // some changed value
});
```

There is no easy way to re-trigger polymer expressions, actually I don't know of any other than little hacks (for template lists, etc) that in the end cause more problems then help.

Comment: Yes, I know i could register an eventListener for "translations-loaded" event(or any other) and .fire it after translations are loaded. After I could iterate all the observers and could call their observedCallback_ method.... This will also do the job. Even a could create an array with messages waiting for translations and call only their observer's method.....but I just wonder if there is another way to do the trick. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Well, you need to tell the expressions that your value has changed in one or the other fashion. I don't think you get around with either re-triggering the observers or implementing a event based logic. However, you could implement the event based solution on a global base and use data binding to push the values down to the components, e.g. you have one fire and one listener which will handle it. Just need to make sure that every component requiring translation is exposing a translation-variable that can be used as a trigger. At least in this case you won't to have alter every component.

Comment: Just have to engineer the component in a way to reflect this.